# extracting from the list with condition in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list which contains data frames with three columns and different number of rows. As an example one of them is as the table below. df[[2]].
I want to extract for each of the data frame the row where the column "D" is "TRUE" for the first time. for example, the row number 5 in the table below. How can I extract the information? And how can I extract the first and last element of colunmn A from my list? I tried below:

```
df$first_element_A = unlist(X = df, FUN = function(p_)
{
 p_[which(p_$A)][1]
}))





df$A = 40.51
df$m = 15
df$D = TRUE
```

I have reach to this code, but not sure how to fix it:

```
df$A = sapply(X = df, FUN = function(p_) {which (p$D==TRUE )[1]}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe

```r
lapply(df, function(x){head(x[x$D, ], 1)})
```

Answer (score 1):

First I created two reproducible dataframes in a list. You could use `lapply` where you extract in each dataframe from your list where the rows has TRUE in column D. You can use the following code:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(m = c(runif(6, 0, 16)),
                 A = c(runif(6,0,16)),
                 D = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE"))
df2 <- data.frame(m = c(runif(6, 0, 16)),
                 A = c(runif(6,0,16)),
                 D = c("FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE"))

my_list <- list(df1, df2)

lapply(my_list, function(x) head(x[x$D == "TRUE",], 1))
#> [[1]]
#>            m        A    D
#> 5 0.09949959 10.60356 TRUE
#> 
#> [[2]]
#>          m        A    D
#> 2 9.154188 8.434005 TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to fix your initial attempt using `which()`

```
lapply(df, function(p) p[which(p$D)[1], ])
```

**edit** answer to follow up question. I assume you mean how to get the first and last elements of column A in the original list.

```
df <- list(
  df1 = data.frame(m = 21:26,
                  A = 41:46,
                  D = c(F,F,F,F,T,T)),
  df2 = data.frame(m = 11:14,
                  A = 31:34,
                  D = c(F,T,T,T)))

> df
$df1
   m  A     D
1 21 41 FALSE
2 22 42 FALSE
3 23 43 FALSE
4 24 44 FALSE
5 25 45  TRUE
6 26 46  TRUE

$df2
   m  A     D
1 11 31 FALSE
2 12 32  TRUE
3 13 33  TRUE
4 14 34  TRUE
```

In the list, first element of column A would be 41, and last element would be 34.

```
> first_in_A <-  df[[1]][1,"A"]
> first_in_A
[1] 41
> last_in_A <- df[[-1]][nrow(df[[-1]]),"A"]
> last_in_A
[1] 34
```

Comment: @Quinten  thanks. how can I extract the first and last element of colunmn A from my list? I tried the codes in the update.

Comment: I assumed the question was for me since you tried to use the solution using `which()`.  The function `which()` returns the index of T in a T/F vector, so trying to use `which(p$A)` will give you an error because "A" is numeric. You can access the values of the list directly,`df[[1]]` will give you the first dataframe, then `df[[1]][1,"A"]` will give the first row of column "A". I assume that's what you wanted. Not sure.